# JS with batch process

Tags: javascript, batch-file

I am having a Java batch process which I used in C# to run process. I want to have a testcase to check whether the batch process is running or not. I used the batch process as: void … batch_process(string process) { try { string strFilePath = Path.Combine(batch_process_path, process); ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(strFilePath …

Comment: @Don't Panic can you advice me on this

Comment: If you remove "your" code the `accept` callback fires for every file. You also have an error in your code `html: "+` ... I assume that should be double single-quotes (instead of a single double-quote).

Comment: @Jasen : I've fix the code error you mentioned on single quotes. BTW do I need to remove accept call back? var ext = file.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase() so how can I acces file object ?

Comment: I assume you want to make use of the accept callback. I do see that you're reusing `id` for the generated buttons -- that's duplicate ids if you have multiple files.

Comment: @Jasen : Any solution for that. what basically I want is when I drop files. if there any files with 'mov', 'wav' extensions, swal will load popup and based on button clicked a value will assigned while uploading. pls advice

Comment: @Jasen : "'re reusing id for the generated buttons " I didn't get this part. can you explain it

Comment: `<button type="button" role="button" tabindex="0"  id="checkone">` gets created for every file. If you do not destroy this after you're (immediately) done then that's a duplicate id which is not valid.

Comment: @Jasen : Can you advice me with a sample code .

Comment: Is this the widget you are using? https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/

Comment: @Jasen : Yes it is